# Можно ли в при помощи react-hook-form вызвать ошибку за пределами формы(аналог stopSubmit из redux-form )?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет. У меня есть формочка логинизации, в которой я хочу добавить ошибку, которую можно было бы вызвать, как бы, за пределами формы(видел такое в redux-form). Конкретно я пытаюсь воспроизвести примерно такой функционал: на сервер отправляется запрос, если ответ от сервера положительный, то все хорошо, погнали дальше, если же сервер вернул ошибку, то мы вызываем какую-нибудь ошибку по типу "Неправильный email или пароль", но вот как это сделать я не совсем понимаю. Пытался найти что-то подобное в документации, но или я чего-то не понимаю, или в react-hook-form ничего подобного нет. Возможно, есть еще и другие варианты, вызывая ошибку не там, где планирую я, буду рад услышать любые.

```
export const logIn = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
    loginAPI.logIn(email, password).then(data => {
        if (data.resultCode === 0) {
            dispatch(authMe())
        } else {
            // Вот тут я хочу вызвать ошибку
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: вы это рассматривали? https://react-hook-form.com/api#errors

Comment: Мне казалось, что это немного не то. Но ладно, спасибо, я попробую поглубже разобраться)